# How to redirect/rewrite URL using HAProxy (change context path)

Tags: redirect, haproxy

This question is related to HAProxy 1.4.27.
I have an application that can be accessed using the context path '/foo/foobar?..." like below:

```
http://www.myserver.com/foo/foobar 
or 
http://www.myserver.com/foo/foobar/showDetails.do?id=1002
```

The context path now has changed to '/foobar' lately, but the users have the old URLs bookmarked. I was trying to redirect the user to the new context using the 'redirect' configuration in haproxy.cfg but that only works if the url is an exact match. Is there a way to configure the haproxy.cfg to redirect to

```
http://www.myserver.com/foobar 
or
http://www.myserver.com/foobar/showDetails.do?1002
```

This is the redirect configuration that I am using:

```
redirect location /foobar/ if { url /foo/foobar/}
```

I tried using the 'reqirep' too but was not able to configure it properly (haproxy process throws errors while trying to restart).

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, version 1.4.2x does not support URL rewrite (even though the URL redirection works on the server side using 'reqirep'). We will be upgrading to version 1.5.x that supports the feature.

Posting this answer so that it may help someone who comes across the same scenario.